# How do I know if a Nessus Scan against a Oracle instance has been sucessful?

Tags: oracle, nessus

I have a Nessus Policy with all the Oracle plugins activated and the rest of the plugins disabled. I ran the scan against a fresh installation but I get nothing but the `Oracle TNS Listener Remote Poisoning` vulnerability.

Is there any plugin that helps to know if the scan credentials worked out or not?

Any other recommendations creating database policies will be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the Nessus log to see what checks it performed, what plugins it used / attempted to use.

**Steps**

- In the scan settings, make sure `Log Scan Details to Server` is checked
- Execute the scan
- After the scan, check the log file in: `/opt/nessus/var/nessus/logs/nessusd.messages`